# Use of audio in project

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, win32com

I used the following Python 3 script to generate an audio file :

```
>>> import win32com.client
>>> speaker = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")
>>> speaker.Speak("Hello There")
```

I want to know if I can use the audio file in any personal commercial project

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions for legal advise are not suited for SO.

Comment: Fair point. In my answer I did mention a Law Stack Exchange question that is similar, so perhaps that will suffice or it could be moved to LSE?

Comment: @Neil The person asking did not even point out which legislation applies for him/her. Copyright laws differ a lot per country, so I'm not sure if there could be any advise better than generic information about the topic.

Comment: I agree with @KlausD. This question has nothing to do with programming. It's not possible to answer it without looking carefully into the license of the library and knowing more details about the use cases. There are other, probably better places to ask this kind of questions.

Comment: @KlausD having thought more, I think you're right too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the underlying concern here is the copyright status of the audio you've created. You should check the licence terms for the SAPI voice you used, and for complete reassurance you would need to check with a lawyer. If you own the copyright or the output is licensed for commercial use then you would be fine.

A similar discussion occurred with this Law Stack Exchange question here: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/8572/was-is-the-copyright-status-of-audio-files-created-with-microsofts-text-to-spee

That said (and this is in no way to be construed as advice!) there are a high number of monetised YouTube videos with synthesized voices, so you may be okay but it seems a reasonable thing to seek a precise answer as you have here, or failing that, with a lawyer.